# Preload, prefetch e preconnect, pra que servem?

Tags: html5

Vejo em vários sites esses valores **Preload, prefetch e preconnect** no attr *rel* de certos links, porém não entendi exatamente a sua funcionalidade.

Para que exatamente eles servem? Quando utilizar?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> **preload**: Especifica que o agente do navegador deve buscar e armazenar de forma previa o recurso destino atribuído pelo atributo:

Primeiro carrega o conteúdo do atributo;

```
    <link rel="preload" href="/styles/style.css" as="style">
```

Obs: *Vai carregar o conteúdo style.css na memoria, utilize quando for um arquivo pequeno, um arranjo de tema.*

> **prefetch:** Especifica que o navegador deve carregar e armazena em cache(disco) no navegador, para uso na próxima navegação ou quando for solicitado no futuro;

```
  <link rel="prefetch" href="/styles/style.css" as="style">
```

Primeiro carrega o arquivo "style.css" armazena em cache, para uso na proxima navegação;

Referência: https://www.w3.org/TR/resource-hints/#dfn-prefetch

Obs: *Vai carregar no cache(disco) seu arquivo css para uso futuro.*

> **preconnect**: Verifica se é possivel connectar a origem do conteúdo do atributo;

```
 <link rel="preconnect" href="https://cdn.algumrecurso">
```

Obs: *Iniciando uma conexão, que inclui a pesquisa de DNS, handshake TCP e negociação TLS opcional, permite que o agente do usuário mascarasse os altos custos de latência quando for estabelecer uma conexão.; Também tem o **dns-prefetch** que é similar ao **preconnect***

Referência: https://www.w3.org/TR/resource-hints/#preconnect

Enquanto o **preload** armazena em memoria do navegador o **prefetch** armazena no cache(disco), o **preconnect** verfica se é possivel conectar a origem dos recursos caso consiga, o **User Agent** do navegador deixa conexão pré estabelecida;

Referência https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_rel.asp

Comment: Esse segundo exemplo, não deveria ser `rel="prefetch"`?

Comment: Sim, obrigado @JeffersonQuesado! Corrigido...

Comment: Coloquei buscar de forma previa @AndersonCarlosWoss que é carregar, mas vou corrigir para melhorar

Comment: Valeu @AndersonCarlosWoss, corrigido, escrevi de cabeça rápido e não li da nisso.

Answer (score 7):

São três possíveis, [entre tantos outros](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types), para o atributo `rel` do elemento `link`.

## preload

```
<link rel="preload" href="style.css" as="style">
```

Indicar o valor `preload` faz com que o cliente (navegador) busque por este recurso o mais rápido possível. No fluxo *normal*, o navegador iria somente requisitar este recurso quando renderizar a página, imediatamente antes, melhor dizendo, o que, dependendo do caso, pode bloquear a primeira renderização e aumentar o tempo de carregamento. Ao indicar o recurso como `preload`, você estará indicando que este recurso será utilizado na página muito em breve e que ele deverá requisitá-lo o quanto antes possível, buscando o resultado de, quando o navegador for renderizar a página, o recurso já esteja disponível.

Outras vantagens são:

- O navegador priorizará recursos com mais precisão;
- Antecipa recursos futuros, reutilizando o mesmo, se existir;
- Aplica a política de segurança de conteúdo correta;
- Define os cabeçalhos de requição `Accept` corretos para o recurso;

Utilizando o atributo `as` você aumenta a consistência da sua aplicação informando o tipo de recurso a ser solicitado. Isso é importante, inclusive, para o cliente determinar a ordem de preferência entre eles. Os tipos possíveis são:

- `audio`, arquivos de áudio;
- `document`, arquivo HTML a ser carregado em um `<frame>`;
- `embed`, recurso a ser embarcado em um `<embed>`;
- `fetch`, recurso que será requisitado assíncronamente;
- `font`, arquivo de fonte;
- `image`, arquivo de imagem;
- `object`, recurso a ser embarcado em um `<embed>`;
- `script`, arquivo JavaScript;
- `style`, arquivo CSS;
- `track`, arquivo WebVTT;
- `worker`, arquivo *web worker* em JS;
- `video`, arquivo de vídeo;

Embora parecer uma boa ideia utilizar isso para todos os recursos do site, utilize com cautela. De maneira superficial, o recomendado é que você utilize o `preload` apenas para recursos que serão utilizados para renderizar a página acima da borda, tais como CSS do topo da página, logotipo, banners, fontes, etc. Recursos que serão utilizados abaixo da borda podem ser requisitados de forma natural sem alterar a experiência do usuário.

Mais detalhes você pode ler em [*Preloading content with rel="preload"*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content).

## prefetch

```
<link rel="prefetch" href="/images/big.jpeg">
```

Com o `prefetch` você informa ao cliente para requisitar o recurso de forma silenciosa **após** renderizar completamente a página atual. Ou seja, nenhum recurso que será utilizado pela página deverá ser requisitado com `fetch`. O que o `fetch` faz é *simular* o comportamento futuro do usuário, de modo que seja possível, durante o tempo ocioso do navegador, antecipar as requisições e armazenar em cachê. Por exemplo, se a página atual é a *index*, apresentando um menu, seria sensato você deduzir que futuramente o usuário irá acessar um link deste a fim de entrar em uma página interna. Com o `fetch` você poderá fazer a requisição para essas páginas e armazenar o resultado em cachê e, quando o usuário acessar o link, o resultado cacheado será exibido.

O tempo ocioso do navegador é aquele em que ele já terminou de renderizar a página atual e fica aguardando alguma interação do usuário. O `fetch` utiliza esse tempo para antecipar as requisições e melhorar a experiência do usuário nas interações futuras, pois, como o resultado estará em cachê, o tempo de carregamento será bem baixo.

Como qualquer recurso, utilize com cautela. Utilizar `fetch` para recursos desnecessários poderá sobrecarregar seu servidor com requisições que poderiam ser evitadas.

Outras informações em [Link prefetching FAQ](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Link_prefetching_FAQ).

## preconnect

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs">
```

Como o próprio nome sugere, é uma pré-conexão. O cliente irá requisitar do servidor do recurso uma conexão HTTP da qual nada será transmitido, isto é, o cliente não enviará previamente dados ao servidor bem como o servidor não enviará dados ao cliente. A ideia aqui é justamente antecipar a conexão entre cliente/servidor de modo que as requisições futuras sejam finalizadas em menos tempo.Se você utiliza um servidor de cachê, por exemplo, é uma boa ideia você utilizar o `preconnect` com o servidor, assim todos os recursos que serão requisitados do cachê no servidor serão obtidos mais rapidamente, o que diminui o tempo de carregamento da página.

Comment: No firefox o prefetch não é consistentes. por exemplo, apenas irá pré-pesquisar recursos somente quando o navegador estiver ocioso. Por isso carrega o conteúdo primeiro e  a referência esta diferente no w3school e w3c; E o comportamento diferente no Chrome; Isso merece mais pesquisa

Comment: @alxwca Mas a ideia do `prefetch` é exatamente utilizar o tempo ocioso. Não entendi seu comentário. Em relação às referências, w3schools não deve ser considerada, use apenas a W3C, WHATWG ou MDN (prinicipais). Qual seria o comportamento diferente no Chrome?

Comment: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#link-type-prefetch
There is no default type for resources given by the prefetch keyword.

Sim eu entendi, é que estava pesquisando pra ver com funciona na integra esse prefetch e do porque que ninguem usar a implementação completa do w3c <link rel="prefetch" href="//example.com/next-page.html" as="html" crossorigin="use-credentials">
<link rel="prefetch" href="/library.js" as="script">

No chrome ele é carregado junto com  a pagina  que ele esta porem não é usado.

Comment: Uso no  Gecko, muito melhor, ta ai porque o carregamento da Mozilla é mais rápido.

Comment: Qualquer duvida faz uma implementação cdn e da um F12 pra vc ver. E vá em networking. Ta tudo certo com a implementação só fique curioso

Comment: Essa parte do *default type* refere-se ao valor do atributo `as`, que precisa ser definido.

Comment: Entendi, valeu! Esclarecedor. No Edge nem funciona. Só comportamento do User Agent. A ideia só adquirir conhecimento.